# How to add an enum array in a TypeOrm entity?

Tags: arrays, typescript, enums, entity, typeorm

I am doing a lot of research and experiment to use an enum array in my entity.

```
import { Program } from '../../program/entities/program.entity'
import {
  Column,
  Entity,
  JoinTable,
  ManyToMany,
  ManyToOne,
  PrimaryGeneratedColumn,
} from 'typeorm'
import { Exercise } from '../../exercise/entities/exercise.entity'
import { WeekDays } from '../types/week-days.enum'

@Entity()
export class Workout {
  // [...]

  @Column({
    type: 'enum',
    enum: WeekDays,
    default: [],
    array: true,
  })
  scheduledDays?: WeekDays[]

  constructor(partial: Partial<Workout> | {} = {}) {
    Object.assign(this, partial)
  }
}
```

Unfortunately it gives me this error.

```
QueryFailedError: You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MySQL server version for the right syntax to use near 'array ('monday', 'tuesday', 'wednesday', 'thursday', 'friday', 'saturday', 'sund' at line 1
```

How can I solve this? I can't get what's wrong on my decorator options.

Answer (score 8):

leaving this here for anyone visiting this post for the same issue as me

```
   export enum StringEnum {
        ADMIN = "a",
        EDITOR = "e",
        MODERATOR = "m",
        GHOST = "g"
    }
    
    @Column({
        type: "enum",
        enum: StringEnum,
        array: true,
        default: [StringEnum.ADMIN]
    })
    stringEnums: StringEnum[];
```

Comment: Is this not supposed to work with mysql too?

Comment: did you test this? I am getting the same error for nest.js with typeorm and mysql

Answer (score 0):

Using Postgres 15, this worked for me:

```sql
create table abc (
   some_value TEXT[] NOT NULL
);
```

```js
export enum ServerType {
  SERVER_1 = 'SERVER_1',
  SERVER_2 = 'SERVER_2',
  SERVER_3 = 'SERVER_3',
}

@Column('text', { name: 'some_value', array: true })
someValue!: ServerType[];
```